# What is this matrix doing

Tags: matrices

I am trying to find out what this matrix is doing. I am trying to follow the guide:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg/512px-2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg.png

but I cannot seem to match it up. I am fairly new to matrix multiplication.

The bottom row is the translation.

[image: Matrix1]

*

[image: Matrix2]

*

[image: Matrix3]

I think it is rotating it? But I am really not sure. A detailed explanation of why as well would be great. If no one will provide an answer a link that would explain the transformations would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward, if you ignore the miniscule terms, you roughly get

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1 &0 \\
0&1&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

You will have to realise that this is a 4x4 matrix that works on a vector $(x,y,z,1)$ and represents a rotation + translation (bottom row). This form is traditionally used in 3D graphics because that's how your video card does coordinate transformation and projection.

Anyway, the matrix isn't even a particularly interesting rotation, it's a rotation by $90^\circ$, as it just exchanges $x$ and $z$ components (rotates by $90^\circ$ around the $y$ axis, which obviously stays untouched, se the $1$ on the diagonal).

The same goes for other matrices. Note that the last two are not normalized (the last one will scale the entire system by a factor of 100 and the second will shrink it by a factor of 100 (it does "times 0.01" on top of exchanging some components)).

Comment: Thank you, what I dont understand though is how you got that matrix from what I provided? The ones dont seem to match the positions of the numbers?

Comment: What I'm showing is the first matrix, rounded so that small numbers are set to zero and almost-one numbers are rounded to one (or minus one). See the tiny exponents ($10^{-6}$) in most of the terms. Because this is not exact, the real rotation is a bit different angle (but not much). For illustration purposes, this is fine. Otherwise check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula to see how to set up the rotational part (the translation is mostly separate).